# How to Return JSON in Next.js not-found.tsx?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I am working on a Next.js 14 project where I've set up a custom 404 page using the `not-found.tsx` file placed in the app root. In cases where an endpoint is not found, I'd like to return a simple JSON object instead of the default HTML response.

In regular API routes, I can easily achieve this using `return NextResponse.json({})`, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to accomplish the same in the `not-found.tsx` file.